# httpClient Does not give Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, zoom-sdk

i am trying to call the Zoom Api for Access token. It work Perfectly fine when i am trying to post with postman . 
but from code it does not respond

[ZoomApiLink_StepNo2](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/auth/oauth)

below are the following details

```
 public static async Task<String> PostTogetToken<T>(string requestUrl, string client_Secretkey) {
            ZoomToken hello = new ZoomToken();

            var EncodedURl = ApiService.Base64Encode(client_Secretkey);
            using (var _httpClient = new HttpClient()) {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestUrl))
                    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Basic " + EncodedURl);

                var httpContent = new StringContent("", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(requestUrl)) {
                    Version = HttpVersion.Version11,
                    Content = httpContent
                };

                using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage)) {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    } else {
                        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you calling `Result` or `Wait` further up your call stack?

Comment: @StephenCleary Result

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing a common deadlock problem because code further up the stack is using `Result`, [blocking on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

To fix, change the `Result` to `await` and use [`async` all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Comment: but i am not getting response from

(var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage)

Comment: I suspect that you are getting a response, but the code cannot continue past the `await` due to the deadlock caused by `Result`.

Comment: then how should i overcome this? can you review my code? whre to make chnage? @stephen

Comment: To fix it, change `Result` to `await`, and [allow the `async` to propagate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Comment: This Issue has been resolved by addting ------ 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
before SendAsyc method